# Why is code not executing after response received

Tags: python, paypal, tornado, paypal-sandbox

I'm running the code below and it takes the user to PayPal to make a payment and then returns them to the `return_url` as expected. However the code doesn't execute any further and it doesn't execute the payment.

I have based my code on https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python:

```
class PayPalHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

        paypal.configure({
                             "mode": PAYPAL_MODE, 
                             "client_id": PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
                             "client_secret": PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET})



        payment = paypal.Payment({
            "intent":  "sale",


            "payer":  {
                 "payment_method":  "paypal" },


            "redirect_urls": {
                 "return_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/ty",
                  "cancel_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" },


            "transactions":  [ {

                 "item_list": {
                      "items": [{
                                 "name": "membership",
                                 "price": "2.00",
                                 "currency": "GBP",
                                 "quantity": 1 }]},


                      "amount":  {
                            "total":  "2.00",
                             "currency":  "GBP" },
                             "description":  "One of membership fee." } ] } )

        redirect_url = ""

        if payment.create():
            print("Payment[%s] created successfully"%(payment.id))

            for link in payment.links:
                if link.method == "REDIRECT":
                    redirect_url = link.href
            print("Redirect for approval: %s"%(redirect_url))
            return self.redirect(redirect_url)

        else:
            print("Error while creating payment.")
            print(payment.error)


        response = payment.to_dict()
        print response
        payment = paypal.Payment.find(payment.id)

        if payment.execute({"payer_id": response['payer_id']}):              
            print ("Payment executed successfully")
        else:
            print(payment.error) # Error Hash

        print payment.to_dict()

        print userData
```

So in the example at https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/python?success=true&token=EC-8JL96732FP068791F&PayerID=QQGSRNHDACTLJ. Step 5 is not happening and no response is sent from PayPal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Avi from PayPal here. I am not super familiar with Tornado, but after the line `return self.redirect(redirect_url)` happens in your code, and returns the user to the return_url, in `payment.execute({"payer_id": response['payer_id']})` are you getting the payer_id correctly? Payer_id is returned appended to the return_url as one of the parameters in the format `http://<return_url>?token=EC-60U79048BN7719609&PayerID=7E7MGXCWTTKK2`. Also, what is the status of the payment after you execute `payment = paypal.Payment.find(payment.id)`. The other suggestion I would have is to see if `print payment.error` prints a useful debug message and a debug_id which paypal merchant technical services can use to look at the issue.

Comment: Hi Avi, thanks for getting back. My code above works up to getting the return url: `200 GET /ty?token=EC-94017452W19149239&PayerID=QQGSRNHDACTLJ`. After that none of the code seems to get executed. I put in the `print paypal.Payment.error` after ` payment = paypal.Payment.find(payment.id)`. But no statement is printed. But I do get redirected to the `return_url' defined.

Comment: So if you print response['payer_id'] , does that correctly print QQGSRNHDACTLJ for you? If it does my suggestion for debugging would be to [get an access token](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/) and then [execute payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment) via curl calls to check what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You need other url where papypal redirects when the payment had been successful, where you will receive the token and the PayerID. In that GET method, you can put this part of the code (pseudocode):

```
 payerid_param = request.get('PayerID')
 payment = paypal.Payment.find(db_payment.id)

 if payment.execute({"payer_id": payerid_param}):              
    print ("Payment executed successfully")
 else:
    print(payment.error) # Error Hash
```

You will need to save the payment_id between calls.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use

```
return self.redirect(redirect_url)
```

I think you can use just

```
self.redirect(redirect_url)
```

I've never seen return statement in Tornado handlers.